# Join/merge 2d lists

Tags: python, list

Hi I have a for loop that creates a 2 d list on each iteration with the following structure

```
listStructure = [(,1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

The probleme is that i have the following code

```
l = []
for element in range(2):
     a function that returns the above mentioned listStructure
     l.append(listStructure)
```

and this returns the following structure

```
l = [[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)],[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]]
```

Is there a method to either ensure that list has the following structure

```
l = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

or a method to post process this after the fact to have the above mentioned structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list.extend`:

```
lst = []
for element in range(2):
     # a function that returns the above mentioned listStructure
     lst.extend(listStructure)
```

---

Note: Don't name your variable `list`, you're shadowing  python [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-list).

Answer (score 0):

*method to post process this after the fact to have the above mentioned structure*

You might flatten your result using `itertools.chain` following way

```
import itertools
lst = [[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)],[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]]
lst = list(itertools.chain(*lst))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Note that itertools.chain return iterator so I use `list(...)` to get `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the variables of python built-in type.
you can change the variables name to num,num1 or ls.
what ever you wan but not python built-in type.